# I have encountered some issues regarding Blazor connections

Tags: javascript, c#, blazor

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyVE6.png)
I've created a demo that implements image scaling functionality using JavaScript and Razor. Uploading works fine, but when I try to crop the image, I encounter this prompt. 'attempt to reconnect to the server：1 of 8'  and console show 'blazor.server.js:1 [2023-08-09T08:43:06.014Z] Error: Connection disconnected with error 'Error: Server returned an error on close: Connection closed with an error.'   Additionally, my project is a mixed Blazor project with both Blazor WebAssembly and Blazor Server components. The cropping function works fine, but there's a text prompt that appears for several seconds afterwards. This is hard to accept.Can some one provide some assistance，thanks...

Codes:

imageSharp.js

```
    var resize;
    var base64data;

window.Crop = {
    image: function (component) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            var cor = document.getElementById('upload-demo');
            var input = document.getElementById('upload').files[0];
            if (input) {
                if (resize) {
                    resize.destroy(); 
                }
                resize = new Croppie(cor, {
                    enableExif: true,
                    viewport: {
                        width: 150,
                        height: 150,
                        type: 'square'
                    },
                    boundary: {
                        width: 300,
                        height: 300
                    }
                });
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    resize.bind({
                        url: e.target.result
                    });
                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(input);
            } else {
                
            }
        }, 150);
    },

    responses: function (component) {
        resize.result('blob').then(function (blob) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
            reader.onloadend = async function () {
                var base64data = reader.result;
                var i = document.getElementById('result');
                var img = document.createElement('img');
                img.src = base64data;
                i.appendChild(img);
                return component.invokeMethodAsync('ResponseMethod', base64data);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

_Host.cshtml（I use library  croppie ， it need add ）

```
head： <link href="./lib/croppie/croppie.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


body： <script src="./lib/croppie/croppie.min.js"></script>
       <script src="./js/imageSharp.js"></script> //path
```

razor：

```
@page "/testP"
@inject IJSRuntime JS


<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="custom-file">
        <input id="upload" accept="image/*" type="file" class="custom-file-input" @onchange="Upload">
        <label for="upload" class="custom-file-label">label</label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="upload-demo">
    <div class="upload-msg">msg:</div>
    <div class="upload-demo-wrap">
        <div id="upload-demo"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<button class="upload-result" @onclick="Up">Abr</button>
<div id="result"></div>
<img id="result-img" src="">



@code {

   

    async Task Upload()
    {
        await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("Crop.image", DotNetObjectReference.Create(this));
   
    }

    async Task Up()
    {
        await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("Crop.responses", DotNetObjectReference.Create(this));
    }

  

}
```

```
image
```

I'm not very familiar with Blazor and JavaScript, so  hope for your understanding...

Comment: Try capturing the exception in JS : https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_errors.asp

Comment: i find I lost handle  ‘ component.invokeMethodAsync('ResponseMethod', base64data)’  thank you.

Comment: Did you solve issue?   You need to debug function where error is occurring and find out which variable is causing issue.